# Git remove submodule and add another fork back

Tags: git, github

I am forking [mapbox-ios-sdk](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk.git) off Github. The mapbox-ios-sdk uses [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) as a submodule. I want my own [custom version of FMDB](https://github.com/t2wu/fmdb)  (actually just adding a sqlite3.h from another project), hence I want my own fork of the sdk.

So on my own fork I tried to remove the original FMDB submodule and added my own fork. I removeed the submodule as according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule). Then I added my own FMDB fork in the **same directory** as the original FMDB submodule by:

`git submodule add https://github.com/t2wu/fmdb ./MapView/Map/FMDB`

Now I run into what I can't explain. The above command doesn't work! It would download FMDB alright but I won't see sqlite3.h in `./MapView/Map/FMDB/src`. (And `git log --graph` I do not see my own commit of sqlite3.h and I'm on master.) However if I just put it elsewhere, say

`git submodule add https://github.com/t2wu/fmdb ./MapView/MapView/FMDB`

or

`git submodule add https://github.com/t2wu/fmdb FMDB`

Then I do see sqlite3.h. What could be happening? Does it has anything to do with CocoaPod which mapbox-ios-sdk also apparently support?

Comment: Did you try git submodule init and git submodule update ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you removed the old submodule, the metadata still remains within .git/modules/MapView/Map/FMDB.

Since git 1.7.8, git stores submodule metadata in the parent repository's .git directory, rather than a separate .git within the submodule.  That's why you see the old submodule's history and working tree.

To get everything back in shape, go to the base of your parent repository and run:

```
git submodule sync
cd MapView/Map/FMDB
git fetch
git checkout origin/master
```

Comment: If I'm to start afresh. To cleanly remove a submodule, do I now need to manually remove the entire directory at .git/modules/MapView/Map/FMDB?

Comment: After committing the removal of the submodule I remove the said directory. I add my own fork of the module back and it works. Thanks a bunch. I've been wrestling with this for hours!

Comment: You don't even need to do that.  The important part is running the sync, which tells git to fetch objects from your FMDB fork instead of the original.